# Query builder in a queued command in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, queue, query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.0 and I've created a queued command with the Artisan CLI:

```
php artisan make:command SendEmail --queued
```

I need to use the DB::table() query builder method into this command, but I'm not able to make it work.

This is an excerpt of my code:

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use App\Commands\Command;
use DB;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class SendEmail extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldBeQueued {

use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

protected $message;

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function handle()
{
    $data = DB::table('structures')->where('id', '=', '1')->first();
    // $data is always empty even if database connection works outside the command!!! <-------------------
    // no error exception is thrown
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I had to restart the supervisor queue in order the code to be correctly re-read:

```
supervisorctl
supervisor> restart myQueue
```